# data issue addEventListener in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener, postmessage

I've to pass some data from `iframe` to parent.

`iframe` code

```
window.parent.postMessage({message: 'Test'}, "*");
```

Parent Code

```html
  window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    alert('Received message 1 : ' + e.data.message);
    document.getElementById('ExchangeID').value=e.data.message;
  }, false);
```

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. When i run this in IE9 , I get an error that `e.data.message` is *undefined*.

What is missing here ?

Comment: Thats because IE9 doesn't allow you to send an object. You could just do `window.parent.postMessage('test', '*');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Can I Use... page on Cross-document Messaging](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage):

> [image]
>
> Partial support in IE8-9 refers to only working in frames/iframes (not other tabs/windows). Also **in IE 9 and below an object cannot be sent using postMessage**.

You can, however, use the alternative syntax:

```
window.parent.postMessage("test", "*")
```